# JQuery auto-complete formatting by putting HTML in "label" response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery auto-complete and sending a response with "label" and "value".
I'm trying to get the label to have formatted HTML. The json_encode escapes the html formatting I'm trying to pass through.

Should I do this differently? How can make json_encode not escape the html formatting (it changes "/" to "\/")?

Example code:

```
$return[$i]['label'] = $row['text'];
$return[$i]['label'] = "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $row['text'] . "</span> - " . row['name'];  

json_encode($return);
```

and when I just check the url response manually, I can see he's escaping the "" to "<\/span>"

Comment: Please post your current code (possibly as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example) so we can take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure which auto complete you are using. If you are using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/, your problem is not json  the label doesn't support html by default

**The label is always treated as text, if you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js). The demos all focus on different variations of the source-option - look for the one that matches your use case, and take a look at the code**

You can do something like this. What the code is doing is showing the autocomplete matching text in yellow.

```
function autoCompleteRender(ul, item) {
    var searchTerm = this.term;
    var itemLabel = item.label;
    itemLabel = itemLabel.replace(new RegExp("(" + searchTerm + ")", "gi"), '<strong class="itemhover">$1</strong>');
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + itemLabel + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
}


$(yourselector).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            //your source
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = autoCompleteRender;
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined" see http://jsfiddle.net/Vjbd4/

Comment: The key is to use data("ui-autocomplete") not data("autocomplete")

Comment: Here is the extra code you need: https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js and don't forget to include `html:true` in autocomplete. Works great now!

Comment: And here is demo: https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/demo/autocomplete/html.html - what you put for `label` and `value` matters.